# fetching dynamic data and showing in picker gives me error

Tags: react-native

```
  constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {

            make :[]
        }

}

componentWillMount(){

                          fetch('http://link.com', {
                          method: 'GET',

                        }).then((response) => response.json())
                              .then((responseJson) => {
                                if(responseJson.message === "List of Years"){
                                  var length = responseJson.result.length.toString();
                                  let newarray=[];
                                  for(var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
                                  //  newarray.push(responseJson.result[i].Makes.year_name.toString());
                                        this.setState({
                                            make: [...this.state.make, responseJson.result[i].Makes.year_name]
                                        });
                                  }
                                  //this.setState({make : newarray})

                                }
                            }
                              ).catch((error) => {
                                console.error(error);
                              });
    }


     <Picker

                 mode="dropdown"
                 selectedValue={this.state.selected}
                 onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({selected: value})}>
                 {this.state.make.map((item, index) => {
                     return (<Item label={item} value={index}/>)
                 })}
              </Picker>
```

I made a state named make in construtor and then in componentWillMount() function i fetched data from server and then it set state to make array.But it looks like there is problem with my code.It throws error:

```
TypeError:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'child.props.value')
```

I also tried with  but problem remains.What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: As a general suggestion: fetch data in `componentDidMount`. `componentWillMount` is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-render.

Comment: Also consider that the correct way to set items in the Picker is `<Picker.Item ... />`